# how to display my facebook friend list using Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.2.3)?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Using Php can I get all my facebook friends who are greater than 25 years old. I have use the follwoing code but didn't get any success.

```
$api_key = '{APP-ID}';
$secret  = '{APP-SECRET}';

include_once 'facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook($api_key, $secret);
$user = $facebook->getUser(); 

if ($user) {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($friends["data"] as $value) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<div class="pic">';
        echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $value["id"] . '/picture"/>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="picName">'.$value["name"].'</div>'; 
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: what error you are getting??

Comment: I am getting the 2 following waring:


1. Warning: Illegal string offset 'appId' in D:\xampp\htdocs\facebookfriendlist\facebook-php-sdk-master\src\base_facebook.php on line 251





2.Warning: Illegal string offset 'secret' in D:\xampp\htdocs\facebookfriendlist\facebook-php-sdk-master\src\base_facebook.php on line 252

Comment: try this `$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me', 'GET');`.. instead `$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which tutorial you followed but that's the incorrect way of creating a `Facebook` object.

Replace your starting code with-

```
include_once 'facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php';

$config = array(
   'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
   'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
   'allowSignedRequest' => false // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

You must follow the official [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted) of using the PHP SDK.

Comment: Hello Sahil,

when I used your given format than I get following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\facebookfriendlist\facebook-php-sdk-master\src\base_facebook.php on line 1340

Comment: Whenever requesting for `/me` without auth, this exception is thrown. To handle this thing, use the code mentioned here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/

Comment: Quick question, is this 3.2.3 version of the php sdk compatible with the new facebook api v2?

Comment: Nope! Use SDKv4 for v2.0 Graph API : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4